# Pasar un JSON anidado en Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estoy pasando un JSON, para crear un User con un objeto Account, referenciado como FK. Solamente en este último se pasa un id existente, pero salta una excepción de que el id no puede ser nulo.

Toda la codificación está en la pregunta en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132680/how-to-pass-nested-json-with-only-id-in-the-second-spring-boot

Cómo tiene que hacer tanto el service como el controller para añadir el User relacionado con el Account?

Muchas gracias :)

P.D.: Console generado

```
2020-07-29 11:38:43.141  INFO 14172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9898 (http) with context path ''
2020-07-29 11:38:43.144  INFO 14172 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.conexiona.ConexionaApplication       : Started ConexionaApplication in 6.526 seconds (JVM running for 8.967)
2020-07-29 11:38:43.146 DEBUG 14172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]
2020-07-29 11:38:43.147 DEBUG 14172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Immediately restarting application
2020-07-29 11:38:43.147 DEBUG 14172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@10c515a9
2020-07-29 11:38:43.147 DEBUG 14172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Starting application com.practicas.conexiona.ConexionaApplication with URLs [file:/C:/Users/canro/IdeaProjects/project_example/target/classes/]
2020-07-29 11:38:56.911  INFO 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-29 11:38:56.912  INFO 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-29 11:38:56.912 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-07-29 11:38:56.920 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-07-29 11:38:56.920  INFO 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2020-07-29 11:38:56.930 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/api/v1/addUser", parameters={}
2020-07-29 11:38:56.933 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.rest.UserController#createUser(User)
2020-07-29 11:38:57.030 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.example.model.User@2802b333]
null
2020-07-29 11:38:57.427 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler com.example.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler#globleExcpetionHandler(Exception, WebRequest)
2020-07-29 11:38:57.446 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-07-29 11:38:57.447 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [com.example.exception.ErrorDetails@4ddbc615]
2020-07-29 11:38:57.466  WARN 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!]
2020-07-29 11:38:57.466 DEBUG 14172 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

JSON de entrada:

```
{
    "account": {
            "accountId":"06xxxx-5fxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
    },
    "userName":"user3",
    "emailAddress":"user3@gmail.com",
  "password":"123",
    "enabled":"1",
    "lastLogin":"2020-07-28"
}
```

JSON de salida:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-07-29T08:00:05.608+0000",
  "message": "The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!",
  "details": "uri=/api/v1/addUser"
}
```

Clase User:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "accountId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Integer enabled;

    @Column(name = "lastLogin")
    private String lastLogin;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserGroupUser> userGroups = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor, Getters and setters

}
```

Clase Account:

```
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private String accountId;

    @Column(name = "accountName")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String company;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "dicomId")
    private String dicomId;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Integer enabled;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "account",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "account",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<>();

    //Constructor, Getters and setters
}
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String userId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found on :: "+ userId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) { return userService.addUser(user); }

    @PutMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String userId,
            @Valid @RequestBody User userDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found on :: "+ userId));

        final User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(userDetails, user);
        if  (updatedUser == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedUser);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteUser(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String userId) throws Exception {
        User user = userService.findUserById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found on :: "+ userId));

        userService.deleteUser(user);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }

}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findUserById(String userId){
        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public User addUser(User user){
        User userExisted = userRepository.findById(user.getUserId()).get();
        Account accountExisted = accountRepository.findById(user.getAccount().getAccountId()).get();

        if(userExisted != null || accountExisted == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            user.setAccount(accountExisted);
            return userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User updateUser(User userDetails, User user){
        Account accountExisted = accountRepository.findById(userDetails.getAccount().getAccountId()).get();

        if( accountExisted == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            user.setEmailAddress(userDetails.getEmailAddress());
            user.setUserName(userDetails.getUserName());
            user.setAccount(userDetails.getAccount());
            user.setPassword(userDetails.getPassword());
            user.setAccount(accountExisted);

            return userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser (User user){
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, copia aquí el código. Además, en lugar de poner el mensaje de error, sería mejor tener el "stack trace" generado

Comment: @PabloLozano Hecho, por favor es de máxima urgencia.

Comment: No hay urgencia en las preguntas, mira [esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4771/bajo-qu%c3%a9-circunstancias-puedo-agregar-urgente-o-frases-similares-a-mi-pregunt)

Comment: Me falta el método del controller: me parece que el fallo está ahí, porque el log dice que no está recibiendo parámetros

Comment: @NicolasOñate Está bien, no era mi intención de apresurar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás usando el modelo (la clase `User`) como DTO (Data transfer object) en el controller, por lo que las validaciones hacen que sea necesario que la instancia llegue ya con un ID válido.

Mi consejo es desacoplar el modelo de persistencia de la capa de presentación: crea un `UserDTO` (por ejemplo), que sea lo que se reciba en el controller. En este DTO puedes poner las anotaciones necesarias para que `@Valid` funcione correctamente, obviando que userId es el ID y por tanto permitiendo que sea nulo.

De hecho, si trabajas con SonarQube, esto [genera un warning al compilar](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-4684):

> Persistent entities should not be used as arguments of
> "@RequestMapping" methods

Un poco fuera de tema, pero si quieres un método "RESTful" para crear usuarios, la URL debería ser `api/v1/users` y ya: al ser una petición POST ya se deduce que estás añadiendo uno nuevo. El verbo sobra, como correctamente ya has omitido en el resto de métodos.

Comment: Lo tendré muy en cuenta, muchas gracias. Un saludo cordial.